# "My question regards/concerns/relates to the following topic"

Tags: phrases, vocabulary

Can I say

> My question regards [an object]"

as a way of saying

> - My question is regarding...
> - I have a question regarding...

I like the brevity of it.

Comment: _Concerns_ is what you want in the first sentence: _My question concerns `X`_. _Regard_ doesn't sound right there. _A question regarding `X`_ is OK, but not a main verb.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you for suggestion _concerns_! It's the perfect replacement and doesn't sound off the way _regards_ does.

Comment: This question may be a good fit for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @medica With **regarding** here a preposition, and **regard** a verb, some lateral thinking i.e. a search for analogy may be of use. First let me confess my personal bias: I prefer "My question regards language" to "My question is regarding language" and I prefer neither (in favor of the question itself) to either of the two at all. Now, let us build another preposition-versus-verb-phrase construct: "The hypothesis is involving language" could be replaced by "The hypothesis involves language" and both could be left out in favor of the hypothesis itself.

Comment: Do see this guide entitled "How To Ask Questions The Smart Way" - which I myself use frequently - here: [link](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these phrases seem to work well. For more info on usage, check out [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regards).

*Opinion:*

"About/In relation to", I think is definitely safer and more versatile with "regarding" coming in second.

Answer (score 2):

You can say, *my question regards*, but you would be in the minority here. If you google that construction, you gat a decent number of hits, but if you look at the quality of the hits, it's mostly personal blogs and questions to other bloggers.

On the other hand, *question concerns* comes up in solid writing, if you will, like the New York Times and professional sites, as does *question relates (to)* and *question regarding*.

Generally, I would choose *concerns* for brevity.

> - I have a question *regarding* politics.
> - My question *concerns* politics.
> - My question *relates to* politics.

but not

> - *my question *regards* politics.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those are all OK. But it is simpler and shorter to say just "*My question is* ***about***..." or "*I have a question* ***about***...."